# IBM MQ..publishing a message to a topic

Tags: postman, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

I am currently testing ibm-mq using **postman** i am able to add messages to the queues on the cloud. I am successfully adding and retrieving messages from a particular queue.

Adding a message -

- Need to get **ibm-mq-rest-csrf-token** by hitting the following api..

> (**POST**) https://{your-remote-cloud}/ibmmq/rest/v1/login

```
Body will a json

{
"username" : {username}
"password" : {password}
}
```

This will give you back a token in the cookies.

- sending the message -

> **(POST)**
>   https://{your-remote-cloud}/ibmmq/rest/v1/messaging/qmgr/{Queue
>   manager name}/queue/{Queue name}/message

the ibm-mq-rest-csrf-token as the header and the body the message you are sending..

**Question - 
I want to add messages to a particular topic.**

I am not able to find any documentation or examples to do this.. 
Can someone direct me to an example or some form of documentation..
I can work with curl requests to publish too if someone knows anything about that..

Comment: How do you configure postman to put messages to queues?  Can you update the question by clicking edit and adding the configuration and/or code you use (don't add it as a comment).

Comment: @JoshMc i have added the info.. 
I think ill write  separate Q&A to answer this in a better way

Comment: From my understanding the IBM MQ REST API does not support publish API.  You could define a topic object that specifies the topic string,  then define a qalias that targets that topic object.   Once this is done you can "put" to the qalias the same as you described and it will be publish to the corresponding topic string.   This would require settings up 2 objects per topic string.  The id that puts to the qalias also needs pub permission on the topic string. I can write up this as a answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoshMc yes the latest one has no documention of this.. but from what ive read the older versions (before it was renamed and updated to the latest versions).. There were api's to post to a topic.. i was hoping someone had figured it out.. or had some leads about it... 

I will try out your suggestions and see if it helps my case.. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the older versions (before it was renamed and updated to the latest versions).. There were api's to post to a topic".  As far as I know since REST was added in 9.0 it never supported topics.

Comment: In god knows what corner of the ibm documentation i had found /topicstring to post to a topic...  ( not able to find it anymore :/ ) 
\

Comment: I guess you are referring to WebSphere MQ Bridge for HTTP. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q033190_.htm